# Encourage SemanticImport to assume numbers?

Tags: dataset

I would like to import a CSV without specifying the data type of each column before hand. `SemanticImport` almost does it, but doesn't appear to recognize numeric columns when there is a mixture of integers and reals. A simple example:

```
str = "0,0.4\n0,0.3\n0,0\n0.2,0.1";
ds = SemanticImportString[str, HeaderLines -> 0]
(* ds[-1,1] = Missing["Unrecognized",0.2] *)
```

Without specifying the type explicitly, how can I get a number rather than a missing value?

Comment: `ImportString` handles mixed data types as well: `Map[Head, ImportString[str, "CSV"], {2}]`

Comment: I ran into this problem too.  Unfortunately specifying data types makes import ridiculously slow.